# Binding To An Array Within An Array with an Ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array within an array that I'm trying to bind to. I then want to use an ng-repeat to show all "Name" items of that second array in a blank div container. My code looks like this:

```
$scope.workflows = [{
    Id: 1,
    Name: "Name of first workflow(*don't want to repeat*)",
    Description: "Education focus area requests",
    Steps: [{
        Id: 1,
        Name: "**Name I DO Want to Repeat**",
        Description: "The concept paper listed below",
        Action: "Get Approval From",
        Obj: "Program Officer - Group",
        AdditionalInfo: "n/a",
    }, {
        Id: 2,
        Name: "**Name I DO Want to Repeat**",
        Description: "Describe",
        Action: "Do things",
        Obj: "n/a",
        AdditionalInfo: "n/a",
    }, {
        Id: 3,
        Name: "**Name I DO Want to Repeat**",
        Description: "Describe",
        Action: "Do things",
        Obj: "n/a",
        AdditionalInfo: "Additional",
    },
]},
```

This is HTML

```
<div class="commentContainer" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="textBlue" ng-repeat="workflow in selectedWorkflow track by $index" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 7px; margin-bottom: 5px">
        {{selectedWorkflow.Name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

(This is where my selected workflow comes from)

```
$scope.selectedWorkflow = {};
$scope.selectWF = function(wf) {
        $scope.selectedWorkflow = wf;
        console.log(wf);
        $scope.goAway = 1;
    }
```

What code should I change in my ng-repeat and in my binding, to get to that "Name" object in my second array to repeat and not the "Name" object from the first array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to print steps of a `selectedWorkflow`, correct? So, iterate (i.e. `ng-repeat`) over `selectedWorkflow.Steps`:

```
<div ng-repeat="step in selectedWorkflow.Steps track by $index">
   {{step.Name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks SO much! I've tried everything but that and IT WORKED! Im new at this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="commentContainer" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="textBlue" ng-repeat="step in selectedWorkflow.Steps track by $index" 
          style="width: 100%; margin-top: 7px; margin-bottom: 5px">
            {{step.Name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming that you simply want the list of steps of the selected Workflow.

If that's the case, then you need to ng-repeat over the selected workflow's steps. In that case, in the above template, each 'step' will represent one object in workflow.Steps array.